# Brownie Error cannot find contract/file

Tags: brownie, import

Hello I was starting to write some `solidity` code with brownie as eth-environment, I tried to compile the code and the import statement is showing en error -

```
ParserError: Source "@smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
```

Actually I have 2 import statements and both of them was showing error, I sorted the first one out by adding current release version from `github`, but this one is not sorted and it keeps showing error, here is my `solidity` imports -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

I edited the `brownie-config.yaml` file -

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.7.2
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.7.2'
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.2'
```

Any help with some explanation would be of great help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in your smart contract you need to have the standard import pathing:
ie:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

You may have to download the contracts before deploying, but compiling should download them I believe.

```
npm install @chainlink/contracts --save
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install the chainlink-brownie-contracts package by

```
brownie pm install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
```

That still hadn't worked for me.
I then needed to follow the directory in which brownie installed the package. In my case it was

```
/Users/<your username>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/
```

There, I didn't find the v0.8 folder but v0.7.
So in the FundMe.sol file I just changed the import directory to

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol"; //importing Chainlink interface
```

Then everything worked.